# How can I hide extra volume controls?

Tags: sound, gnome-panel, applet

Currently I have sound controls in both the indicator applet and the notification area applet.  Does anyone know how I to hide the audio controls in the notification area?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is `gnome-volume-control-applet` still in your startup applications (in the *System -> Preferences* menu)? If it is, just disable it and you shouldn't see it in the future.